# Is the new Visual Studio for Mac (Xamarin Studio) any different to the Visual Studio on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, ide

I know the new Visual Studio for Mac that came out sometime this year is a rebranded Xamarin Studio. I am just wondering if Visual Studio on Windows is also Xamarin Studio now or it is still an update from the previous Visual Studio branch?

PS: been a developer on Mac for over 10 years now. Haven't been in touch with Windows' side of IDE... trying to do some catch up.

Comment: Visual Studio for Windows is Visual Studio for Windows, no change there other then the updates for the 2015, 2017, etc releases...., Xamarin Studio for Windows is deprecated

Comment: thanks @SushiHangover

Comment: @SushiHangover given that Visual Studio for Windows and Visual Studio for Mac is essentially two different software, do they currently have matching features (can make problems for Android, iOS, Windows, MacOS)?

Comment: The `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` features are the "same"  and thus solutions/projects can be opened by both IDEs (assuming that you  have Xamarin installed within Visual Studio for Windows and both have matching Xamarin versions installed) without any issues, now on the macOS, you can not open/develop UWP or other Window's *only* project types and they are disabled within VS4M's solution explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows Xamarin Studio is now deprecated and was replaced with Xamarin for Visual Studio. On macOS Xamarin Studio is still in development, but was rebranded 2016 as Visual Studio for Mac. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin